# Android Studio figuring out stack trace

Tags: android

I'm making an app in Android, and it crashes when I do a certain thing (I know what makes it crash, but I don't know why and how to solve it), So I think I need to read the stack trace but I don't know a lot about it.

as far as I know you are supposed to run with debug and the stack trace is in the logcat but the stack trace there, is not the current one and I don't know which part is about the crash help please Thank You.

I see this piece red every time it crashes is this the one?

```
 10-08 21:08:08.501 26243-26546/? E/WindowState: getStack: Window{11f9ccba 
 u0 d0 com.redot.puzzle3/com.redot.puzzle3.MainActivity} couldn't find 
  taskId=1199 
Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getDisplayContent:1059 
com.android.server.wm.WindowState.isDefaultDisplay:1778 
 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.getMultiWindowStyleLw:2363
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Choose the first one and open you manifest see what happens

Comment: that option doesnt show up so i think its already has been aded

Comment: I have a very weird problem. I've created an interface and when i send it to the main activity and from there i do a transaction to the fragment im sending the data to but i only can send the data to fragment more than 3 meaning i cant replace the fragment layout for the first 3 fragments it crashes